# What is the advantage of using widetext package instead of cuted package?

Tags: two-column, cuted

I was looking for an answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70489/text-spreading-onto-both-columns-in-middle-of-twocolumn-layout) which is, by the way, unanswered :(

After searching this site, I read many questions similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151365/koma-script-scrbook-twocolumn-formatting-and-wide-equation-problem/151507), and I found out that all of the answers suggested the use of `widetext` package.

But after looking in the code of `widetext` package, I found that it basically uses the `strip` environment from `cuted` package.

Am I missing something? Apart from those rules (which I don't understand/like) what is the advantage of using `widetext` package rather than `cuted` package?

Here are two examples where the code looks similar (the `widetext` package just paints those rules, adds a `\par` and adds `\parindent \@parindent`, two indents?).

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{kantlipsum,widetext}

\begin{document}
\kant[1-2]
\begin{widetext}
    \kant[4]
\end{widetext}
\kant[5]
\end{document}
```

And the other one

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{kantlipsum,cuted}

\begin{document}
\kant[1-2]
\begin{strip}
    \kant[4]
\end{strip}
\kant[5]
\end{document}
```

Here you can download the package [`widetext`](https://svn.einsteintoolkit.org/documents/Paper_EinsteinToolkit_2010/widetext.sty).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your interested in my question. You should know that `cuted` (and therefore `widetext` as well) has the problem of corrupting vertical spacing in some cases. Try to fill your page with one-line itemize items and you should see it.

Comment: @tohecz Yes. I wrote 50 lines in an enumerate (one line per item) before the `strip` environment and it “broke” the space between items 27 and 28. In my case this does't affect me, but thanks for telling us :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you are right; they are basically the same; the `widetext` package defines its `widetext` environment using `strip` from `cuted.sty`, but adds the rules. In fact, the author of `widetext` says in the `.sty` file:

> %% This package just defines the widetext environment and the rules.

The other difference is that `widetext` gives you indentation for the first line of paragraphs, but `cuted` doesn't; this is done by `widetext`, using the ineternal length `\@parindent` to store the value of `\parindent` before the environment, and then using this value inside the `widetext` (that's the meaning of the line `\parindent \@parindent` in `widetext.sty`).

An image comparing `widetext` and `strip` (notice, in particular, the indentation for `widetext` but not for `strip`):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum,widetext}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{strip}
\lipsum[4]
\end{strip}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{widetext}
\lipsum[4]
\end{widetext}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

In short:

Advantages of `widetext`: the rules and indentation for the firs line of paragraphs. I personally don't the rules much, but they are there "to guide the reader" (the idea of the rules was taken from the `widetext` environment defined in `revtex4.cls`).

Disadvantage of `widetext`; the author didn't take any precautions to prevent the rules to be detached from the text; so you can get the initial rule at the bottom of a page, then the text beginning on the next page.

Comment: Two subquestions: (1) why the rules? Could you explain what are they meant to be? I don't understand them, and they don't look good in my opinion; and (2) why double indentation? I don't understand why he copies `\parindent` and then uses both `\parindent \@parindent`, resulting in a double sized indent. I guess that's all, I missed that line of the code: `%% This package just defines the widetext environment and the rules`.

Comment: @Manuel I also don't like the rules; according to the author, they are there to guide the reader: a quote from an answer in the link to latex-community mentioned by the author: "Since the flow of text goes from the first column to the second, comes backs to the first one and finally continues on the second, two horizontal rules are placed to guide the reader. "

Comment: @Manuel As I explained in my answer, there's no double indentation. The line `\parindent \@parindent` simply assigns to `\parindent` the value `\@parindent` (which is the paragraph indentation before the environment); in this way, the default document indentation is inherited by the environment.

Comment: Well, there is a double indentation (in your image, for example). If my eyes don't lie to me.

Comment: @Manuel Ah, now I see what you mean. But, that result was not the intention of the author; the line `\parindent \@parindent` was meant to be a simple assignment; however, you're right and in my image there's a bigger indentation inside the environment; that's something weird with `scrartcl` and the value of `\parindent`; changing to `article`, the indentation is the same.

Comment: The "double indentation" is a standard typographical stuff, however, in this context, a bit weird: You use smaller indentation in `twocolumn` mode than in one-column, since simply said the column is too narrow for full indentation. However, in this case it would be prefered to have the same indent in both environments.

Comment: @tochez; Ah, so the KOMA classes use a value for the indentation in one column mode approximately equal to twice the indentation in two column mode?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: No, it’s visually the same.

Comment: @Speravir then I guess I am not understanding tochez's comment...

Comment: If you mix onecolumn and twocolumn mode, you have two options: be somehow _correct_ and use larger indent in onecolumn than in twocolumn, or to be somehow _consistent_ and use the small indent in both. I just checked how I do it in the journal, and I use a larger indent in onecolumn than in twocolumn, but I never mix them up so close to each other: either the whole article is onecolumn, or it's only the abstract at the very beginning in onecolumn and the rest is twocolumn.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: It was a general remark not related to KOMA-Script. You've read his comment in between I'm sure.